# Objective C MasterViewController Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, switch-statement

I am having a problem with a semantic issue I am getting in my **MasterViewController.m**. The issue I am getting is this:

```
MasterViewController.m:89:1: Control may reach end of non-void function
```

And the same error on this line:

```
MasterViewController.m:105:1: Control may reach end of non-void function
```

It is happening at the end of both of my switch statements, but I am not exactly sure why. All I am trying to do is make sections in my **MasterViewController.m**.

I am two days new into Objective C, so it could be a really simple problem I am simply looking over because I am not familiar with all of the errors yet. So if anyone could point me in the right direction, it wold be appreciated.

My Code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (section)
{
    case 0:
        return [_section1Items count];
        break;

    case 1:
        return [_section2Items count];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}

- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (section)
{
    case 0:
        return @"This is section 1";
        break;

    case 1:
        return @"This is section 2";

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your methods don't return anything but they are supposed to return an Integer (`NSInteger`) and the reference to an `NSString`.

Just add some meaningful return statement to your default branch. e.g. `return 0` for the first method and `return nil` or `return @""` for the second.